# I want to compare the value with the all array element

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, count

I want to compare all element of array with my variable. If some element is bigger than my variable do something. But i want to make loop in array elements in every case.

```
e1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
e2=[1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10]
e3=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
e4=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for d in e2:
  if d>=4:
    print(d)
```

Comment: then, code works fine. What is your problem here?

Comment: If it is redundant then write a `function` for it ;)

Comment: Do you want to loop over all `e1` and `e2` and ... ?

Comment: The intent of the question is not clear. Could you rephrase / provide better example ?

Comment: Do you want to compare all elements of every array in one pass?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do:

```
e = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
e[e>4]
```

Hope it will help =)

Adrien